# Free Usenet reader for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, usenet

I know about Unison. Are there any decent free usenet readers for Mac OS X Leopard?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the title to 'Free Usenet reader for Mac OSX'

Comment: done

Comment: My solution has been to use a Windows computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mozilla Thunderbird](http://getthunderbird.com) does a decent job with usenet.

Comment: Doesn't seem to handle binaries very well.

Comment: Can't find a UI action to "Cancel" a posting in Thunderbird version 17.0.8

Answer (score 3):

You can get the standard *nix ones via [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). I'm partial to [slrn](http://slrn.sourceforge.net/), but that's a console app. If you prefer a gui, there's [Pan](http://pan.rebelbase.com/). I've used it on Linux, and it was good. I can't speak to how well it works in OS X. (The Pan webpage mentions OS X as supported, so that's a good start.)

If you are comfortable tracking down dependencies and compiling, you can also build these on a Mac without Fink or MacPorts, but the package managers make upgrades and removal a lot easier.

Comment: Works well but seems to be a memory hog. I will have to keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after *binary* newsreader (i.e., you just want a tool to aggregate and reassemble binary postings), you might want to take a look at [ninan](http://www.ninan.org) - since its web/java based it should be pretty platform agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

I second Pan (install via MacPorts).
Thunderbird (v3.0.1) becomes painfully slow and often crashes with larger lists.
Another option (though limited in the number of headers it will download) is: MT-Newswatcher http://www.smfr.org/mtnw/

Answer (score 1):

I should go for [NZBin](http://www.nzbin.info)

NZBin is a free Usenet client for the Mac OS X with a great GUI and has all features included (auto repairing, extracting, etc.). And it is the fastest client I've ever seen.