# Best usenet client for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Usenet reader for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/18232/free-usenet-reader-for-mac-os-x)

Just want to know which usenet client for Mac is the best

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with [Unison](http://www.panic.com/unison/).

Answer (score 2):

Unison if you're reading newsgroups.

[SABnzbd+](http://sabnzbd.org/) if you're downloading files.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like [MacSOUP](http://www.haller-berlin.de/macsoup/) (I liked it well enough in the OS9 days to buy it) but these days I just use Emacs with Gnus to read Usenet news. That way I've got a cross-platform reader and can easily share configurations between machines.