# What keyboard-friendly news readers exist for OSX?

Tags: mac, usenet, newsreader, newsgroups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Usenet reader for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/18232/free-usenet-reader-for-mac-os-x)

I'm interested in keyboard-navigation-friendly usenet clients for OSX. I have tried (and bought) Unison and Thunderbird, but both of these end up requiring a fair amount of mouse use to move around. What I want is something I can task-switch to, check my latest updates, and switch away from, all without having to take my hands off of the keyboard.

I should clarify; this is for an internal, private nntp server, so Google Groups and sundry -- basically all web news readers -- won't do for me.

Comment: Given that there are very few news readers, this topic is not much different from the potential duplicate.

Comment: Excellent catch; sorry, didn't see that when I asked it.

Comment: ... although the specific requirement to handle private nntp servers isn't addressed in that other question, now that I look at it. Reconsider?

Comment: Please flag your post for moderator attention, but it still holds: There are about, well, two currently maintained news readers for Mac OS X, the rest is more or less abandoned or ported from Linux/UNIX and available via packet managers. If your requirements aren't satisfied with one of them, you're out of luck.

Comment: Actually, that comment counts as an answer, I guess.  "No" is still an answer :)